# return value from function with combobox

Tags: winforms, powershell

I have a small GUI that will connect to a vCenter in a list. The forms open in the order I want, but I can't carry values between them. I've tried so many return calls I don't know what else to do.

Here is the code. Basically, the first form opens and asks for which vCenter you want. Then prompts you to authenticate (this all works wonderfully). But the problem comes in after the script is done. I don't get any return values.

```
function Connect-Vc ($vcArg)
 {  
  $Form2 = $null
  $selectedVC = $vcArg.selecteditem
  $viconnection = $null
  if ($global:defaultviserver -ne $null)
  {
   Disconnect-viserver * -confirm:$false
  }
  $clusterselection = $null
  $DropDownTo = $null
  $credential = Get-Credential -Message "Please Enter Elevated Credentials To Access $selectedVC.  You can enter assuming you're an administrator on $selectedVC."
  $username = $credential.Username
  $password = $credential.GetNetworkCredential().Password
  $viconnection = connect-viserver $selectedVC -User $username -Password $password

  [void] [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Windows.Forms")
  [void] [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Drawing")
  [void] [System.Windows.Forms.Application]::EnableVisualStyles()
  $Form2 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
  $Form2.AutoSize = $True
  $Form2.AutoSizeMode = "GrowAndShrink"
  $Form2.width = 600
  $Form2.height = 500
  $Form2.Text = ”Vcenter Selection”
 $Form2.StartPosition = "CenterScreen"

  #First item selection*******************

  $DropDownLabel1 = new-object System.Windows.Forms.Label
  $DropDownLabel1.Location = new-object System.Drawing.Size(140,10) 
  $DropDownLabel1.size = new-object System.Drawing.Size(130,30) 
  $DropDownLabel1.Text = "$selectedVC"
  $Form2.Controls.Add($DropDownLabel1)

  $DropDownLabel2 = new-object System.Windows.Forms.Label
  $DropDownLabel2.Location = new-object System.Drawing.Size(10,10) 
  $DropDownLabel2.size = new-object System.Drawing.Size(100,40) 
  $DropDownLabel2.Text = "Connected to Vcenter"
  $Form2.Controls.Add($DropDownLabel2)

  #Second item selection*******************
  [array]$clusterselection = get-cluster
  $DropDownTo = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox
  $DropDownTo.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(140,50)
  $DropDownTo.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(130,30)
  $DropdownTo.DropDownStyle = 2
  ForEach ($Item2 in $clusterselection) 
   {
        [void] $DropDownTo.Items.Add($Item2)
      }
  $Form2.Controls.Add($DropDownTo)

  $DropDownLabel3 = new-object System.Windows.Forms.Label
  $DropDownLabel3.Location = new-object System.Drawing.Size(10,50) 
  $DropDownLabel3.size = new-object System.Drawing.Size(100,40) 
  $DropDownLabel3.Text = "Select Cluster Location"
  $Form2.Controls.Add($DropDownLabel3)

  #Third item selection*******************
  $DropDownType = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox
  $DropDownType.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(140,90)
  $DropDownType.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(130,30)
  $DropDownType.DropDownStyle = 2
  ForEach ($Item3 in $typeOfServer) 
   {
        [void] $DropDownType.Items.Add($Item3)
      }
  $Form2.Controls.Add($DropDownType)

  $DropDownLabel4 = new-object System.Windows.Forms.Label
  $DropDownLabel4.Location = new-object System.Drawing.Size(10,90) 
  $DropDownLabel4.size = new-object System.Drawing.Size(100,40) 
  $DropDownLabel4.Text = "Select Type of Server"
  $Form2.Controls.Add($DropDownLabel4)

  #Fourth item Input*******************
  $InputName = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Textbox
  $InputName.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(140,130)
  $InputName.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(130,30)
  $InputName.MaxLength = 15
  $Form2.Controls.Add($InputName)

  $inputLabel = new-object System.Windows.Forms.Label
  $inputLabel.Location = new-object System.Drawing.Size(10,130) 
  $inputLabel.size = new-object System.Drawing.Size(100,40) 
  $inputLabel.Text = "Enter Name of Server"
  $Form2.Controls.Add($inputLabel)

  #Fifth item selection*******************
  $dropDownMem = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Combobox
  $dropDownMem.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(140,170)
  $dropDownMem.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(130,30)
  $dropDownMem.DropDownStyle = 2
  ForEach ($Item5 in $mem) 
   {
        [void] $dropDownMem.Items.Add($Item5)
      }
  $Form2.Controls.Add($dropDownMem)

  $DropDownLabel5 = new-object System.Windows.Forms.Label
  $DropDownLabel5.Location = new-object System.Drawing.Size(10,170) 
  $DropDownLabel5.size = new-object System.Drawing.Size(100,40) 
  $DropDownLabel5.Text = "Select Memory Quantity in GB"
  $Form2.Controls.Add($DropDownLabel5)

  #Sixth item selection*******************
  $dropDownvCpu = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Combobox
  $dropDownvCpu.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(140,210)
  $dropDownvCpu.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(130,30)
  $dropDownvCpu.DropDownStyle = 2
  ForEach ($Item6 in $vCpu) 
   {
        [void] $dropDownvCpu.Items.Add($Item6)
      }
  $Form2.Controls.Add($dropDownvCpu)

  $DropDownLabel6 = new-object System.Windows.Forms.Label
  $DropDownLabel6.Location = new-object System.Drawing.Size(10,210)
  $DropDownLabel6.size = new-object System.Drawing.Size(100,40) 
  $DropDownLabel6.Text = "Select Virtual CPU's"
  $Form2.Controls.Add($DropDownLabel6)

  #Seventh item selection*******************
  $dropDownOS = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Combobox
  $dropDownOS.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(140,250)
  $dropDownOS.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(130,30)
  $dropDownOS.DropDownStyle = 2
  ForEach ($Item7 in $operatingSystem) 
   {
        [void] $dropDownOS.Items.Add($Item7)
      }
  $Form2.Controls.Add($dropDownOS)

  $DropDownLabel7 = new-object System.Windows.Forms.Label
  $DropDownLabel7.Location = new-object System.Drawing.Size(10,250)
  $DropDownLabel7.size = new-object System.Drawing.Size(100,40) 
  $DropDownLabel7.Text = "Select Operating System"
  $Form2.Controls.Add($DropDownLabel7)

  #Defines buttons for click to accept*********************
  #$Button1 = new-object System.Windows.Forms.Button
  #$Button1.Location = new-object System.Drawing.Size(10,300)
  #$Button1.Size = new-object System.Drawing.Size(100,20)
  #$Button1.Text = "Provision Vm"
  #$Button1.Add_Click({Provision-VM})
  #$Button1.Add_Click({Get-Account $oRphanedAcct})
  #Defines buttons for click to accept*********************
  $Button2 = new-object System.Windows.Forms.Button
  $Button2.Location = new-object System.Drawing.Size(10,330)
  $Button2.Size = new-object System.Drawing.Size(100,20)
  $Button2.Text = "Provision Vm"
  $Button2.Add_Click({Provision-VM -arg1 "$choice4" -arg2 "$choice5" -arg3 "$Choice3"})
  #Defines buttons for click to accept*********************
  $Button3 = new-object System.Windows.Forms.Button
  $Button3.Location = new-object System.Drawing.Size(140,330)
  $Button3.Size = new-object System.Drawing.Size(100,20)
  $Button3.Text = "Close Form"
  #$Button3.Add_Click({Return-Drop})
  $Button3.Add_Click({$Form2.Dispose()})
  #Defines buttons for click to accept*********************
  $Button4 = new-object System.Windows.Forms.Button
  $Button4.Location = new-object System.Drawing.Size(275,330)
  $Button4.Size = new-object System.Drawing.Size(100,20)
  $Button4.Text = "Ok Button"
  $Button4.Dialogresult = [System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult]::OK
  $Form2.AcceptButton = $Button4
  $Form2.Controls.Add($Button2)
  $Form2.Controls.Add($Button3)
  $Form2.Controls.Add($Button4)
  $Form2.Topmost = $True
  $Form2.ShowDialog()
  $Form2.refresh()
  return $DropdownTo.SelectedItem
  return $DropDownType.SelectedItem.ToString()
  return $InputName.SelectedItem.ToString()
  return $DropDownMem.SelectedItem.ToString()
  return $DropDownVcpu.SelectedItem.ToString()
  return $DropDownOS.SelectedItem.ToString()
  return $Button3
  return $Button4
 }

#Main function definition********************
 function Menu
 {
  $clusterselection = $null
  $global:defaultviserver = $null 
   [array]$VCItems = "VCSelection","VCSelection2","VCSelection3"
  [array]$typeOfServer = "Vanilla", "IIS", "SQL", "SQL_Cluster_Node"
  [array]$operatingSystem = "Windows2012", "Windows2016"
  [array]$mem = "2","4","6","8","10","12","32","64"
  [array]$vCpu = "2","4","6","8","10","12"
  #Function for Closing Form Upon no input
  function Return-Drop 
  {
   If (($dropDownVC.SelectedItem -ne $null) -or ($DropDownTO.SelectedItem -ne $null) -or ($DropDownType.SelectedItem -ne $null))
   {
    $Form.Close()
   }
  }
  #Function for connecting to Vcenter

  [void] [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Windows.Forms")
  [void] [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Drawing")
  [void] [System.Windows.Forms.Application]::EnableVisualStyles()
  $Form = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
  $Form.AutoSize = $True
  $Form.AutoSizeMode = "GrowAndShrink"
  $Form.width = 600
  $Form.height = 500
  $Form.Text = ”Vcenter Selection”
 $Form.StartPosition = "CenterScreen"

  #First item selection*******************
  $DropDownVC = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox
  $DropDownVC.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(140,10)
  $DropDownVC.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(130,30)
  $DropDownVC.DropDownStyle = 2
  $DropDownVC.TabIndex = 0
  ForEach ($Item1 in $VCItems) 
   {
        [void] $DropDownVC.Items.Add($Item1)
      }
  $DropDownVC.SelectedItem = $DropDownVC.Items[0]
  $Form.Controls.Add($DropDownVC)
  $DropDownLabel1 = new-object System.Windows.Forms.Label
  $DropDownLabel1.Location = new-object System.Drawing.Size(10,10) 
  $DropDownLabel1.size = new-object System.Drawing.Size(100,40) 
  $DropDownLabel1.Text = "Select Vcenter to connect to"
  $Form.Controls.Add($DropDownLabel1)
  #Defines buttons for click to connect to VC*********************
  $Button5 = new-object System.Windows.Forms.Button
  $Button5.Location = new-object System.Drawing.Size(290,10)
  $Button5.Size = new-object System.Drawing.Size(100,20)
  $Button5.Text = "Connect"
  $Button5.Add_Click({$form.visible = $false;$t = Connect-Vc -vcArg $DropDownVC})
  $Form.Controls.Add($Button5)
  $Form.Topmost = $True
  $Form.Add_Shown({$Form.Activate()})
  $Form.ShowDialog()
  $Choice1 = $DropDownVC.SelectedItem.ToString()

    enter code here

 return $Choice1
 }
```

Comment: Please reduce that wall of code to a [mcve].

Comment: If you want to pass data between your functions, then scope variables in the `$script:` scope for reuse.